# How Secure is this MySQL statement in a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

How secure is this MySQL statement built in a PHP? Would it be vulnerable to an SQL injection?

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table VALUES(%d, %d, 1, NOW())", 
                 mysql_escape_string($_SESSION['client']['id']), 
                 mysql_escape_string($_POST['id']));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes because %d only results in a number there is no need to escape the string. Using single quotes would provide a speed improvement too. So a safe and fast way is:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT IGNORE INTO my_table VALUES(%d, %d, 1, NOW())', $_SESSION['client']['id'], $_POST['id']);
```

Comment: Got any recent benchmarks for your claim on single quotes improving speed in this instance?

Comment: No benchmarks, but it's more of a common sense thing.  Before sending the string to sprintf - with double quotes, the interpreter will try to look for $variables and other escaped sequences.  The single quotes, it won't.  Though the speed difference is too small to really make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

No it shouldn't be vulnerable.

Here is a detailed article on how to secure your **SQL** queries in **PHP**.

http://www.tech-evangelist.com/2007/11/05/preventing-sql-injection-attack/

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine to me.

In fact, is there any need to use mysql_escape_string in this case, since sprintf("%d") can only result in a number?